# Create a double entry accounting table by separating transactions

Tags: microsoft-excel, sql, power-query

I have an Excel table with accounting transactions that are stored on a single line:

| Date | To Account | From Account | Amount | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-01 | 2192 | 2281 | $100.00 | Transfer |

I'm attempting to convert that single line to double-entry transactions like this:

| Date | To Account | From Account | Amount | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-01 | 2192 |  | $-100.00 | Expense |
| 2023-06-01 |  | 2281 | $100.00 | Revenue |

I've got thousands of entries and will need to update this regularly (multiple times each month), so I'm looking for a systematic way to repeat the process.  The only solution I've found, so far, is to copy the records and than use helper columns to partition the data based upon whether the row is the original or the copy.  I'm open to an Excel, Power Query, SSIS, or SQL solution (the data will end up in a SQL Server database).  I'd like to avoid VBA.

Comment: Most tools like this do not come with accounts and a double entry ledger system, so you would need to build the template.I use QuickBooks for this.

Comment: Is it always going to be the specific columns going into the first and second records? Can you just copy the rows and remove alternating data from each? Vba (macro) should be able to do this pretty easily.

Comment: @john, unfortunately this data is already the result of a poor quality accounting system-that I have no control over.  I need Excel to perform all the analysis that the other system is incapable of.  I'm using SQL Server as the storage system due to historical usage, although it could potentially be moved permanently into an Excel data model.  Regardless the for my analysis, it needs to be in a double entry format.

Comment: @music2myear, yes there is enough consistency that the same columns will be used.  I'd prefer not to use VBA due to restrictions with system security, but I may end needing to and working around those issues.

Comment: Would the downvoter/close voter like to provide any constructive feedback to improve the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another method using Power Query:

- Add an Index column to the original table
- Create two tables from the original table

  - "Credits"

    - Transform the "From Account" entry to null
    - Make negative the "Amount"
    - Make the "Type": Expense
  - "Debits"

    - Transform the "To Account" entry to null
    - Make the "Type": Revenue
- Then

  - Recombine the two tables
  - Sort by the Index column
  - Delete the Index column

*It would also be possible to include decision making based on the account number to decide on the Type, and whether the Amount should be made negative or not.*

```
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Transactions"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Date", type date}, {"To Account", Int64.Type}, {"From Account", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Amount", Currency.Type}, {"Type", type text}}),

    #"Add Index Column" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type","Index"),

    Credits = Table.TransformColumns(#"Add Index Column",{
        {"From Account", each null, Int64.Type},
        {"Amount", each -_, Currency.Type},
        {"Type", each "Expense", type text}}),

    Debits = Table.TransformColumns(#"Add Index Column",{
        {"To Account", each null, Int64.Type},
        {"Type", each "Revenue", type text}}),

    Results = Table.Combine({Credits,Debits}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(Results,{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Remove Index Column" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Index"})
 
in
    #"Remove Index Column"
```

[image]

Comment: That ended up working really well.  Had to modify the code to adjust for complexities I didn't include in the example, but the concept was solid and worked great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Power Query will do this quite easily. Get your data into a table to use as a source, or perhaps use an external data source such as CSV or SQL.

However you get the data into PQ in a format similar to your post, you then want to make sure the Changed Type step is setting suitable data types for each column. Remove the "Type" column which you don't need.

I found it useful to rename "Amount" to "Original amount" at this point so I can reuse that column name later. Select Original Amount and Date, and go to Transform > Unpivot columns > Other columns.

This is the crucial step to get two rows where there was only one. After this you need to add a bunch of conditional columns to get the "To Account" values into a column called "To Account", and nulls for the others, and vice versa for "From Account".

The new "Amount" column is slightly trickier. You can do multiple steps and delete the intermediate columns, or write a custom formula from scratch, or somewhere in between - add a conditional column which looks for To / From and in BOTH cases returns the Amount column. Then in the formula bar, just edit the From half of this by inserting "-1 *" in front of [Original Amount].

Likewise add a conditonal column for Type (Revenue or Expense)

Change the Amount column to Currency data type (or decimal if you prefer, but fixed decimals is useful usually). Remove the unwanted columns so you keep only the columns you need (so get rid of Original Amount, Attribute and Value).

Close and Load - good to go!
Your M code (in Advanced Editor) will end up something like this:

```
let
        Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="StartingTable"]}[Content],
        #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"To Account", type text}, {"From Account", type text}, {"Amount", Int64.Type}, {"Type", type text}}),
        #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Type"}),
        #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Amount", "Original Amount"}}),
        #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Renamed Columns", {"Original Amount", "Date"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
        #"Added To Account" = Table.AddColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "To Account", each if [Attribute] = "To Account" then [Value] else null),
        #"Added From Account" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added To Account", "From Account", each if [Attribute] = "From Account" then [Value] else null),
        #"Added Amount" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added From Account", "Amount", each if [Attribute] = "To Account" then [Original Amount] else -1 * [Original Amount]),
        #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Amount",{{"Amount", Currency.Type}}),
        #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Type", each if [Attribute] = "To Account" then "Expense" else "Revenue"),
        #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Conditional Column",{"Date", "To Account", "From Account", "Amount", "Type"})
    in
        #"Removed Other Columns"
```